# Weblogic 12c with QName

Tags: web-services, jax-ws, weblogic12c

I amm working with weblogic 12c with jax-ws 2.2 to make a webservice client ssl.

My problems are when I create a `javax.xml.ws.Service` in `javax.xml.namespace.QName`.
`javax.xml.namespace.QName qname = new javax.xml.namespace.QName("prueba1", "prueba1");`
`javax.xml.ws.Service create = javax.xml.ws.Service.create(url,qname);`

When I try to construct the Service I get:

`java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: when resolving method "javax.xml.ws.Service.create(Ljavax/xml/namespace/QName;)Ljavax/xml/ws/Service;" the class loader (instance of weblogic/utils/classloaders/ChangeAwareClassLoader) of the current class, org/InstanceInterface, and the class loader (instance of <bootloader>) for resolved class, javax/xml/ws/Service, have different Class objects for the type javax/xml/namespace/QName used in the signature`

Thank you.

Comment: but if i try that like java application its works. I think that can be duplicate libraries about JDK (im using jdk 1.6) with WEbLogic libraries. Im dunno really

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error are because jaspertReport and JRE have libary QName, if you excude xmlapis in your jasperreport error has gone.
This error ocurred because I have same library with same path to call and aplication doesnt know who choice i fixed exllusion that becuase i think is better dont have duplicy library that not mark wich library to use